# How do i use onHourShow callback in a date_popup control with the Drupal Form API

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

I have a drupal form with a single date_popup field. I would like it to just provide the options of 12, 15 and 17 for the hours.

```
$form['order-group']['delivery'] = array(
    '#title'                => t('I Need The Equipment Ready By'),
    '#type'                 => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format'          => 'd-M-Y H:i',
    '#timepicker'           => 'timepicker',
    '#timepicker_options'   => array(
        'rows'            => 3,
        'hours'         => array(
            'starts'    => 12,
            'ends'      => 17,
        ),
        'onHourShow'   => 'onHourShowCallback',
        'minutes'         => array(
            'starts'    => 0,
            'ends'      => 0,
        ),
        'showCloseButton' => TRUE,
        'closeButtonText' => t('Close'),
    ),
    '#default_value'  => date('Y-m-d 12:00',time()),
    '#date_label_position'  => '',
);
```

I then added the following to my javascript file (included with drupal_add_js, earlier in the script)

```
function onHourShowCallback(hour) {
    return hour == 12 || hour == 15 || hour == 17;
};
```

However I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: onHourShow.apply is not a function
    at Timepicker._generateHTMLHourCell (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:797)
    at Timepicker._generateHTML (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:622)
    at Timepicker._updateTimepicker (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:467)
    at Timepicker._setTimeFromField (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:1112)
    at Timepicker._attachTimepicker (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:190)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:1474)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.7.2:2)
    at $.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?v=1.7.2:2)
    at $.fn.init.$.fn.timepicker (jquery.ui.timepicker.js?psw6eo:1470)
    at Object.attach (date_popup_timepicker.timepicker.js?psw6eo:8)
```

I tried asking this in the Drupal stack exchange but was put "On Hold" and told this is a programming question, so I am asking here instead.

Comment: It seems there is a bug in date_popup_timepicker module, the callback (string on the server side) should be passed as a function callback to the client but it is just past as is and remains a string. (line 70 date_popup_timepicker.module )

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was doing everything correctly. :-)

Comment: Hey, just to let you know I had created an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_timepicker/issues/3062256), and I just submitted a patch on the project page (you can quickly check out from the answer below). It sill needs to be tested and reviewed by the community so don't hesitate to leave a comment on the issue page. I had also proposed a patch regarding this compatibility issue with *date_datepicker_inline* module, see [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_timepicker/issues/3062275).

Comment: I'll check it out then let you know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI Timepicker invokes callback functions such as 'beforeShow', 'onSelect', etc. using the method `apply()`, e.g. :

```
var beforeShow = $.timepicker._get(inst, 'beforeShow');
extendRemove(inst.settings, (beforeShow ? beforeShow.apply(input, [input, inst]) : {}));
```

Thus, the type of the callback must be a function - not a string.

The problem is that the module *date_popup_timepicker* does not map string callbacks (passed in from the server) to actual js function callbacks before initializing the timepicker, so once *jquery.ui.timepicker.js* code runs it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: <callback>.apply is not a function`.

On the client side, the datePopup settings object (from Drupal.settings) potentially contains string callbacks, so any of these strings must be converted to its corresponding function *before* calling the timepicker() method. What was missing to get there :

```
var timepicker_callbacks = {
  beforeShow: null,
  onSelect: null,
  onClose: null,
  onHourShow: null,
  onMinuteShow: null
};

function timepicker_callbacks_assign (settings) {
  for (var setting in settings) {
    if (setting in timepicker_callbacks && typeof settings[setting] === 'string') {
      var namespace = window,
          ns_callback = settings[setting].split('.'),
          func = ns_callback.pop();
      for (var i = 0; i < ns_callback.length; i++) {
        namespace = namespace[ns_callback[i]];
      }
      settings[setting] = namespace[func];
    }
  }
}
```

The timepicker() initialization occurs in `Drupal.behaviors.DatePopupTimepicker`, we just need to execute `timepicker_callbacks_assign()` first for the timepicker to get the proper settings.

I created an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_timepicker/issues/3062256) and submitted a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-06-21/date_popup_timepicker-js_callback_assignment-3062256-d7.patch) on drupal.org, it still "Needs Review" so don't hesitate to apply from there and review it.

Comment: I think there's an error in your patch on drupal.org extra "})(jQuery);" bit, but after I removed that it worked like a dream. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I see what you mean but the patch is fine, created with `git diff`, look you'll see a `-})(jQuery);` before a code block addition and a finally the `+})(jQuery);` bit (this is pretty common). You can apply it directly, just checkout the dev branch and run `git apply https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-06-21/date_popup_timepicker-js_callback_assignment-3062256-d7.patch`

Comment: Ah, I see. I applied the patch manually (editing the file).
Great job.